# VueUse useVirtualList issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vueuse

When I try to initialize the virtual list i get the following error message and I don't really understand why :

```
Argument of type 'AppItem[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MaybeRef<AppItem[]>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MaybeRef<AppItem[]>'.ts(2345)
```

Here is the initialization of the virtual list in my Vue Component

```js
const { apps, isLoading, error } = useApps();

const { list, containerProps, wrapperProps } = useVirtualList(apps.value, {
  itemHeight: 22,
});
```

This is the hook where I retrieve my data : **apps**. I'm not sure if this is the cause of the error, but I use tanstack query

```js
const useApps = () => {
  const params = reactive({
    appName: "",
    state: "",
    bucket: "",
  });

  const {
    isLoading,
    data: apps,
    error,
  } = useQuery(["apps"], () => getApps(params));
  return { isLoading, apps, error, params };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should provide `default: []` to your `useQuery` and use `apps` ref as is if you want it to retain reactivity

The problem is you are missing "or []" somewhere - either in `useQuery(..., [])`, `computed(() => apps.value ?? [])` or `apps.value ?? []`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I created a computed method as you suggested and worked perfectly !